# JScrollpane italic IE8 not working correct

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I use JScrollpane version 12 but also had the same problem with earlier versions.

When I make a paragraph or long sentence italic the text goes under the vertical scrollbar in IE8.
All other browsers and versions work well but IE8 not.

Can someone help me to fix this for IE8? When I change Italic back to the normal font, IE8 works fine

Thanks in advance,
Mirjam

Comment: Could you post some images of the problem for better visualization

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution!

The div where the text is in has this css:

```
.content {
     width: 100%;
}
```

When you add a **max-width** to the div like this:

```
.content {
     width: 100%;
     max-width: 700px; // change the width to the width of your text div
}
```

The max-width ensures that in **IE8** the text block won't break when using italic.